# Link error when using of StrCmpIW instead of _wcsicmp in function template

Tags: c++, winapi, vector, string-comparison

I implemented a function template to find a `wstring` in a `std::vector` with case insensitive mode :

```
template <class T>
long VecFindIgnoreCase(const std::vector< T >& vec, const wchar_t* sFind)
{
    for (std::vector< T >::const_iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
        if (StrCmpIW((*iter).c_str(), sFind) == 0)
            return (long)std::distance(vec.begin(), iter);
    return -1;
}
```

In my `code` , compiler gives a link error since using of `StrCmpIW` to compare two strings with case insensitive :

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__StrCmpIW@8 referenced in function "long __cdecl VecFindIgnoreCase<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > >(class std::vector<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > const &,wchar_t const *)" (??$VecFindIgnoreCase@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@@YAJABV?$vector@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PB_W@Z)

But when I'm using of `_wcsicmp` instead of `StrCmpIW` every thing is ok with compiler and  generate no error :

```
if (_wcsicmp((*iter).c_str(), sFind) == 0)    // OK
if (StrCmpIW((*iter).c_str(), sFind) == 0)    // Link error
```

**(BTW i implemented the same function for `string` and used of `StrCmpIA` within and has no error with compiler)**

Any suggestion?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmpiw) says you need to link with `Shlwapi.lib`. Are you?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thats absolutely true. i forgot to add `#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")`

Answer (score 1):

According to [**`@Retired Ninja`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) comment, I just forgot to add `#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")` to link with `StrCmpIW`.